# DanialFarid Ng File Upload issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using your Angular File upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#contrib)

I just have Angular in my project I don’t have Bower or any other stuff.

The issue that I have is all of a sudden it starts throwing the error mentioned below and for some reason even after doing everything I can’t get this to work.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UploadProvider <- Upload 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=UploadProvider%20%3C-
%20Upload at http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:78:12 at 
http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3801:19 at 
Object.getService [as get] 
(http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3929:39) at 
http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3806:45 at getService 
(http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3929:39) at invoke 
(http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3956:13) at 
Object.instantiate 
(http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:3976:23) at 
http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:7315:28 at 
http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-
0.12.0.min.js:8:29473 at wrappedCallback 
(http://localhost:8080/Rsdf/Rsdf_Common/lib/angular.js:11682:81)
```

I have included all these files

```
<script src="Rsdf_Common/lib/ng-file-upload-bower-4.2.4/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="Rsdf_Common/lib/ng-file-upload-bower-4.2.4/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="Rsdf_Common/lib/ng-file-upload-bower-4.2.4/ng-file-upload-all.js"></script>
<script src="Rsdf_Common/lib/ng-file-upload-bower-4.2.4/FileAPI.js"></script>
```

This is my controller definition as you can see I have injected the upload module but it still seems to not work

```
rsdf.controller('fileUploadCtrl',function($scope,$modalInstance,notificationService,$http,userInfo,$timeout,$log,Upload){
```

Need help ...!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got this resolved thanks guys i had missed to add that in the app.js as my dependency i added ngFileUpload dependency and it started to work